# Vacation Time Calculation

Tags: function, date, ms-access, vba

On my Access Database form I have a field that contains a calculation for Vacation time. The current formula is as follows:

```
Function calcVacEarned(asOfDate As Date, HireDate As Date)
  Dim yos As Single

  yos = (asOfDate - HireDate) / 365.25

  Select Case yos
    Case Is > 10
      calcVacEarned = 120
    Case Is > 3
      calcVacEarned = 80
    Case Is > 1
      calcVacEarned = 40
    Case Else
      calcVacEarned = 0
  End Select
End Function
```

However, the time is not coming out correctly. Our vacation time runs from Anniversary date to Anniversary date for the first year and Calendar year the following years.

For example, if I was hired on 11/02/2010, my Anniversary date is 11/02/2011 which will give me 1 year of service and 5 days of vacation. (So I have from 11/02/2011 - 12/31/2011 to take my 5 days or lose them)

Then on 01/01/2012 my vacation time will start over at 5 days going into year 2. (I have from 01/01/2012 - 12/31/2012 to take these 5 days.

On 01/01/2013 I will roll into my 3rd year and recieve 10 days.

I need the function above to represent this... Help!! Thanks

Comment: If I was hired on 06/10/2010 my 1 year date is 06/10/2011, my two year date is 01/01/2012 and my three year date is 01/01/2013.

Comment: It has nothing to do with it it will reset every year.

Comment: If I understand your examples correctly, does this mean you have 0 vacation days during your first 365 days of employment?

Comment: "time is not coming out correctly" is rather vague description of a problem.

Comment: @PowerUser yes that is correct you are not elegible for vacation during your first 30 days of employment.

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov If you read the examples you will understand the problem I am having.

Comment: Nope. Your examples describe desired behavior, they do not say what is wrong with current one.

Comment: @designspeaks is the below what you are after?  Calculating years that are 3 plus by changing the HireDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if I understand your problem correctly this will do what you want.  You just need to change the hire date for years that are greater than 3.

```
Function calcVacEarned(asOfDate As Date, HireDate As Date)
    calcVacEarned = 0

    Dim yos As Single

    yos = (asOfDate - HireDate) / 365.25

    If yos > 1 And yos < 2 Then
        calcVacEarned = 40
    ElseIf yos > 2 Then
        HireDate = "01/01/" & Year(HireDate)
    End If

    yos = (asOfDate - HireDate) / 365.25

    Select Case yos
        Case Is > 10
            calcVacEarned = 120
        Case Is > 3
            calcVacEarned = 80
    End Select
End Function
```